# How to verify that a File Exists in FastReport 4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, fastreport

I have a report written in **DelphiXE** using **FastReport 4**

A picture is loaded dynamically at run time using a file name stored in a table, using the following:

```
procedure Picture1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var  pname : string;                                     
begin
   pname := frxGlobalVariables['imgPath']+ <frxDBDataset1."PHOTO">;                                                      
   Picture1.Picture.LoadFromFile(pname);
end;
```

It runs OK as long as the files are there.  How do I verify that the file to be loaded exists?

I tried using the Delphi **FileExists()** function but it apparently does not exist in **FastReport 4**

---

**UPDATE:**
Using the directions below, I added the FrFileExists function to my report.

I call the code in the report as follows:

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   Photo := imgPath + <frxDBDataset1."PICTURENAME"> + '.jpg';
   if (FrFileExists(Photo)) then Picture1.LoadFromFile(Photo);
end;
```

I ran the runtime designer, and the function is there, but running
the report I get the following:

```
The following error(s) have occured:  
Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (Boolean)
```

And in case you think the variable Photo is not correct, the following code works as long as the picture exists:

```
Picture1.LoadFromFile(Photo);
```

Still need to get it working.

Comment: @Val Marinov:  
 
What is this: // required logic . That is the part I need help with.

Comment: Chuck, you already posted that comment on Val's answer. Val won't be notified of your comment here on the question, only of the one on the answer. But I've already replied to your comment, so if you still need help, ask a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

FastReport allows custom functions to be written and used.

How to do this you can find in : FastReport **DeveloperManual-en.pdf**.

in chapter "**Using Custom Functions in a Report**" page 37, 38, 39

I hope this helps.

**Update**

> **Using Custom Functions in a Report**
>
> FastReport has a large number of built-in standard functions for use
>   in report designs. FastReport also allows custom functions to be
>   written and used. Functions are added using the “FastScript” library
>   interface, which is included in FastReport (to learn more about
>   FastScript refer to it’s library manual).
>
> Let's look at how procedures
>   and/or functions can be added to FastReport. The number and types of
>   parameters vary from function to function. Parameters of “Set” and
>   “Record" type are not supported by FastScript, so they must be
>   implemented using simpler types, for instance a TRect can be passed as
>   four integers : X0, Y0, X1, Y1. There is more about the use of
>   functions with various parameters in the FastScript documentation.
>
> In the Delphi form declare the function or procedure and its code.
>
> ```
> function TForm1.MyFunc(s: String; i: Integer): Boolean;
> begin
> // required logic
> end;
> procedure TForm1.MyProc(s: String);
> begin
> // required logic
> end;
> ```
>
> Create the “onUser” function handler for the report component.
>
> ```
> function TForm1.frxReport1UserFunction(const MethodName: String;
> var Params: Variant): Variant;
> begin
>   if MethodName = 'MYFUNC' then
>     Result := MyFunc(Params[0], Params[1])
>   else if MethodName = 'MYPROC' then
>   MyProc(Params[0]);
> end;
> ```
>
> Use the report component’s add method to add it to the function list
>   (usually in the “onCreate”or “onShow” event of the Delphi form).
>
> ```
> frxReport1.AddFunction('function MyFunc(s: String; i: Integer):Boolean');
> frxReport1.AddFunction('procedure MyProc(s: String)');
> ```
>
> The added function can now be used in a report script and can be
>   referenced by objects of the“TfrxMemoView” type. The function is also
>   displayed on the "Data tree" functions tab. On this tab functions are
>   divided into categories and when selected a hint about the function
>   appears in the bottom pane of the tab. Modify the code sample above to
>   register functions in separate categories, and to display descriptive
>   hints:
>
> ```
> frxReport1.AddFunction('function MyFunc(s: String; i: Integer): Boolean',
> 'My functions',
> ' MyFunc function always returns True');
> frxReport1.AddFunction('procedure MyProc(s: String)',
> 'My functions',
> ' MyProc procedure does not do anything');
> ```
>
> The added functions will appear under the category “My functions”. To
>   register functions in an existing categories use one of the following
>   category names:
>
> - 'ctString' string function
> - 'ctDate' date/time functions
> - 'ctConv' conversion functions
> - 'ctFormat' formatting
> - 'ctMath' mathematical functions
> - 'ctOther' other functions
>
> If the category name is left blank the function is placed under the
>   functions tree root. To add a large number of functions it is
>   recommended that all logic is placed in a separate library unit. Here
>   is an example:
>
> ```
> unit myfunctions;
> interface
> implementation
> uses SysUtils, Classes, fs_iinterpreter;
> // you can also add a reference to any other external library here
> type
>   TFunctions = class(TfsRTTIModule)
>     private
>     function CallMethod(Instance: TObject; ClassType: TClass;
>     const MethodName: String; var Params: Variant):Variant;
>     public
>     constructor Create(AScript: TfsScript); override;
> end;
>
> function MyFunc(s: String; i: Integer): Boolean;
> begin
> // required logic
> end;
>
> procedure MyProc(s: String);
> begin
> // required logic
> end;
> { TFunctions }
> constructor TFunctions.Create;
> begin
>   inherited Create(AScript);
>   with AScript do
>     AddMethod('function MyFunc(s: String; i: Integer): Boolean',CallMethod,'My functions', ' MyFunc function always returns True');
>     AddMethod('procedure MyProc(s: String)', CallMethod,'My functions','MyProc procedure does not do anything'');
>   end;
> end;
>
> function TFunctions.CallMethod(Instance: TObject; ClassType: TClass;
> const MethodName: String;
> var Params: Variant): Variant;
> begin
>   if MethodName = 'MYFUNC' then
>     Result := MyFunc(Params[0], Params[1])
>   else if MethodName = 'MYPROC' then
>     MyProc(Params[0]);
>   end;
> initialization
>  fsRTTIModules.Add(TFunctions);
> end.
> ```
>
> Save the file with a .pas extension then add a reference to it in the
>   “uses” clause of your Delphiproject’s form. All your custom functions
>   will then be available for use in any report component, without the
>   need to write code to add these functions to each “TfrxReport” and
>   without the need to write additional code for each report component’s
>   “onUser” function handler.

**Update2**

To create custom function `FileExists` declare the function in Delphi for example:

```
function TForm1.FrFileExists(FileName : string):boolean;
begin
  // required logic
  Result := FileExists(FileName);
end;
```

Use the report component’s add method to add it to the function list (usually in the “onCreate”or “onShow” event of the Delphi form).

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frxReport1.AddFunction('function FrFileExists(FileName:String):Boolean','My functions',
'This function returns True if file exists');
  frxReport1.DesignReport; //<-- THIS SHOW REPORT DESIGNER RUNTIME
end;
```

Create the “onUser” function handler for the report component.

```
function TForm1.frxReport1UserFunction(const MethodName: string;var Params: Variant): Variant;
begin
  if MethodName = 'FrFileExists' then
    Result := FrFileExists(Params[0])
end;
```

You can not expect to see the functions in the Fast report IDE design time.
To see the function in IDE runtime do :

include `frxDesgn` in uses clause;

use this code to show designer:

```
 frxReport1.DesignReport; //see code On create above
```

Run the project and will see Fast Report Ide and our brand new function `FrFileExists`

[image]

Comment: What is this:   // required logic .  That is the part I need help with.

Comment: Think about it for a moment, Chuck. What if you called `FileExists` there?

Comment: @ChuckO Please see Update2

Answer (score 0):

I don't no why, but MethodName passes the String in UpperCase,
correct the Function to upercase 
MethodName = 'FRFILEEXISTS'

After that it will work (i have test it in my on project)
John

Answer (score -2):

I am glad to find this frFileExists function and since I am using C++ Builder I have it
converted to C++ Builder. After successful compilation, the function does not show up in FastReport IDE.  Can someone help to point out my mistake and thank you very much. My code is appended below:

```
// To create custom function FileExists
boolean __fastcall TForm1::FrFileExists(String FileName)
{
  return (FileExists(FileName.c_str()));
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  frxReport1->AddFunction(L"FrFileExists", L"My Functions",
     L"This function return true if file exists" );
  frxReport1->DesignReport();
}

Variant __fastcall TForm1::frxReport1UserFunction(const UnicodeString MethodName,
      Variant &Params)
{
  if (MethodName == "FrFileExist") {
      return (FrFileExists(Params));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want an answer, you should post a new question. Posting this as a reply to a 5 year old question, makes it invisible.